# How to use Microsoft Edge with Selinum Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

hope that you're fine. I'm trying to run my first Selinuim test but it fails every time, most of the tutorials use Chrome but I'm using Microsoft Edge and I would like to run tests each time on there, I downloaded the right Edge Webdriver version according to edge://settings/help, here what I did in my code and in the project files:
My code:

````
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
//import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
public class Test {
   @org.testng.annotations.Test
   public void test() {
       WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
       System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "msedgedriver.exe");
       driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account");
   }
} ```
The error:
````

[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.3.0
FAILED: test
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest version can be downloaded from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:847)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:134)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:355)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:94)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:123)
at Test.test(Test.java:7)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:132)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:599)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:174)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:822)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:147)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:764)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:585)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:384)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:378)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:337)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:286)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1218)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1069)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1037)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

## ===============================================
Default test
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 0, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNWBD.png)

Comment: Why are you using the chrome driver and not the msedge driver instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "msedgedriver.exe");
```

instead of relative path provide full path

also rearrange the order

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "c:\\somepath\\msedgedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

and instead of chrome use:

```
webdriver.edge.driver
```

use like

```
  System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver","D:\\msedgedriver.exe"); 
  WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();
```

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/driver_requirements/

see the documentation